# How do you call the 'sender' of a UIButton in another function?

Tags: swift, function, sender

I want to call the 'sender' of the pressed button in a new function.

I have created a generic function to perform standard operations within my calculator app. I then want to call this function for each type of operator that I have an IBAction linked to.

```
func standardOperation(sender: UIButton) {

    if isOperator.contains(where: numberLabel.text!.contains) {
        numberLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
        firstValue = true
    } else {
        value = formatTextIntoDouble()
        numberLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
        firstValue = true
    }
}

@IBAction func divideButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    operatorIndex = sender.currentTitle!

    standardOperation(sender: xx)

    operatorLabel.text = "\(prevValue) \(operatorIndex)"

}
```

However, I cannot seem to be able to find the right sender properties as I keep getting an error in the standardOperation(sender: xx) within each IBAction. What is the right way to call the sender of the UIButton that is pressed? I.e., what replaces the xx?

I've tried UIButton or AnyObject but none work.

Comment: `standardOperation(sender: sender)`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in the sender that triggered divideButtonPressed

standardOperation(sender: sender)

I would also take a look at force unwrapping optionals and code defensively.
examples: numberLabel.text! and